# Continuous deployment branch filter in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to setup continuous deployment of our development branch to staging environment in VSTS. Also we have dev environment where deployments should be performed from any branch and only manually.

Having experience with Octopus I was thinking about the following workflow:

- build is triggered from any branch
- release is created after every build
- if branch is *develop* then trigger deployment to staging

I've created a build definition and release definition. My release definition is the following:

[image]

However I don't see anything related to branch / tag filtering in release trigger. Am I missing anything?

**UPDATE**

OK, so I tried old editor, as @Yan and @Harshil suggested and still cannot get it working. Seems like it allows to specify a tag that should trigger the deployment. I did not manage to find a way to provide a branch name. More screens:

[image]
[image]

Comment: The new editor doesn't have this. Try the old editor, you have the edit in old editor button at right top.

Comment: Which source control are you using? I think branches come up only with vsts git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the screenshot, you specified **develop tag** instead of **branch**. You need to specify branch in dropdown box.

[image]

Update:

Regarding build tag, you can add tag to build per to current branch ([Build.SourceBranchName](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables)) by using [##vso[build.addbuildtag]build tag](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) logging command.

Comment: I would be happy to specify a branch there, but I don't have that dropdown :) Also it seems to me that your screenshot is about release creation, but I need to trigger a deployment to particular environment. But I don't have the branch dropdown there as well. http://i.imgur.com/YkB91Vg.png

Comment: @the_joric Does the build use TFVC repository? How do you set the sources? (Get sources)

Comment: @the_joric You need to add tag to build by using logging command (e.g. Write-Host “##vso[build.addbuildtag][tag name, can be use variable)" (I updated my answer)

Comment: thanks, I was looking for easy way to tag the build via script output

Answer (score 2):

I failed to find how to set it up with the new release editor, but the old one has this Triggers tab:

[image]

Comment: yes, I also have seen it in the old editor. Just was wondering if it is really missing, or I am an idiot who cannot spot the obvious thing :)

Comment: and here I am also confused what trigger should be used -- Continuous Deployment or Environment or both? This UI is very nonintuitive

Comment: @the_joric no idea, probably trying out possible options is the fastest way to find the right one...

Comment: The idea in the old editor is triggers defines when a new release should get created like a build is produced from branch x etc while environment conditions defines when an existing release should get deployed on to that environment.

Comment: @AseemBansal yes, I understand that. But still there is no ability to select branch for bitbucket repo :)

Comment: I see. I don't think we support branch filter for bit bucket repositories yet. Let me check with my team members on the plan for this.i will come back to you in case they have additional questions.

Comment: We have added this to our backlog and will take up this feature soon. If all goes well,  then it should be available on VSTS in next few months.